# Is there a way to edit formant using Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, web-audio-api

Currently I'm making an app using Node.js, React and AWS Polly for text to speech. Is there a way to edit formant in audio that I'm getting from Polly using Web Audio API filters or any other javascript way?

Comment: Sure, what exactly you need to do and what did you try?

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev i need to do something like equalizer that will have three options F1, F2 and F3. Right now i have only normal equalizer using biquad filter on frequencies from 60 to 16000.

Comment: Ok, so what did you try yourself?

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev, ok sorry for being a bit stupid. Your comment actually helped, i just needed to define what exactly i need to do, and solution came by itself.